# Storing checkbox tag values to an Javascript Object and String value via JSON

Tags: json, string, checkbox, tags, javascript-objects

I'm probably making some rookie mistakes, but my brain is drained trying to figure out where I went wrong. I have an HTML form, and I need to store JUST the values of the checked selections in an script object (if it's deselected, it should be removed from the object), as well as convert the object into a string. Problem is, I haven't ever had to mix checkboxes with Javascript, and I'm completely lost. When I debug, it completely ignores the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML for the form:

```
    <form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php">
                <div id="errorText"></div>
                <fieldset id="faq">
                <label for="uname">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" required="required">
                <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required">
                <label for="nature" required="required">Nature of your question:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="nature" id="A" value="A">Option A
                <input type="checkbox" name="nature" id="B" value="B">Option B
                <input type="checkbox" name="nature" id="C" value="C">Option C</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="nature" id="D" value="D">Option D
                <input type="checkbox" name="nature" id="other" value="other">Other
                <label for="question">Question(s):</label>
                <textarea name="question" id="question" rows="10" cols="50" required="required">
                </textarea>
                </fieldset><p>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form><p>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
"use strict";

var natureObject = new Object();
var natureSubmission = "";
function checkboxObject() {
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    natureObject = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            natureObject[fields[i].name] = checkBoxes[i].value;
        }
    }
}

function createString() {
    natureSubmission = JSON.stringify(natureObject);
}

/* create event listeners */
function createEventListeners() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    if (box.addEventListener) {
        box.addEventListener("change", checkboxObject, false);
    } else if (box.attachEvent) {
        box.attachEvent("onchange", checkboxObject);
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"nature" is not tagName, tagName is "input".

I suggest to add a class for all checkboxes and use `getElementsByClassName()`, then iterate over them with a `for` loop.

As a side note, I am unsure whether you can have multiple checkboxes with the same `name` in a form submission though.

Comment: The checkboxes used to be radios, but I had to change them since the user needs to select more than one. That could be why they had the same `name`. Just in case, I've changed the names.

I added a class of "box" to each of them. I'm assuming they need the same class name. Shouldn't I be trying to pick up the checked boxes with `getElementsByClassName` instead of tag name since they now have the class name?

Comment: Terribly sorry, that's what I had in mind. Editing answer.

Comment: Apart from that, yes, they should have the same class name, surely enough.

Comment: hmm... still not working. The debugger (Firebug) isn't even budging. I'm not even getting syntax errors. The script is just static.

Comment: Do you iterate over the set returned from `getElementsByClassName`? It is an array, you cannot just set "checked", as it is only a probably nonexistent array key. You need to use `for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++)` then `set[i].checked`. Same for event handler.

Comment: I see that you do use `for` loop but you need to do that with `addEventListener` too.

Comment: It doesn't even fire off. I click a checkbox, it does nothing. Could something be wrong with the event listener?

Edit: Just got your other comments, implementing those.

Comment: Okay, here's what I have. I'm not sure where to implement it in the `addEventListener`. The book I'm going by didn't really explain Event Listeners very well.
EDIT: Edited code in the original post.

Comment: You need another `for` loop in your `createEventListeners` function, and `addEventListener` for each and every checkbox separately. You'll also have to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`, which you do not have.